# Is it possible to tree shake css files in webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, rollup

For e.g. index.css has `.foo{ background:red; }` but `foo` is nowhere used as class name in the application. Is it possible to remove it from the final css bundle ?

Comment: try https://purgecss.com/ it can be used with Webpack. please refer this https://purgecss.com/plugins/webpack.html

Comment: @Zuber is it still a thing in 2024?